# Find aggregated MAX row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't seem to figure this out in SQL Server.

Two tables:

statuses:

```
id   proj   status   changedate
-------------------------------
1    1      1        2015-01-01
2    1      3        2016-01-01
3    1      2        2016-05-01
4    2      1        2016-01-01
... etc
```

projects:

```
id    title        active
----------------------------
1     My project   1
2     No more      0
```

Now I want to list all active projects with its most recent status id. I have tried various kinds of queries but end up with errors.

Tried this among other solution incl HAVING, but no luck:

```
SELECT projects.id, projects.title, statuses.status
FROM projects
INNER JOIN statuses ON statuses.proj = projects.id  
WHERE projects.active = 1 
  AND statuses.changedate = MAX(statuses.changedate)
```

Any SQL Server wizard out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the path that you are on, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, s.status
FROM projects p INNER JOIN
     statuses s
     ON s.proj = p.id  
WHERE p.active = 1 AND
      s.changedate = (SELECT MAX(s2.changedate)   
                      FROM statuses s2
                      WHERE s2.proj = p.id
                     );
```

A more typical solution uses `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, s.status
FROM projects p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.proj ORDER BY s.changedate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM statuses s
     ) s
     ON s.proj = p.id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE p.active = 1;
```

And a more inscrutable way uses `APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.*, s.status
FROM projects p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 s.*
      FROM status s
      WHERE s.proj = p.id
      ORDER BY s.changedate DESC
     ) s
WHERE p.active = 1;
```

Well, this is only inscrutable is you've never seen `APPLY` before.

Comment: Works, thanks. I tried the subquery way before but never figured out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use TOP 1 WITH TIES and order using row_number():

```
select top 1 WITH TIES 
t1.status
, t1.changedate
, p.title
from statuses t1
inner join projects p on p.id = t1.proj AND p.active = 1
order by
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.proj ORDER BY changedate desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from MySql but the syntax should be very similar for SqlServer

```
create table status (
    id int,
    proj int,
    status int,
    change_date date
);

create table project (
    id  int,
    title varchar(64),
    active int
);

insert into status values (1,1,1,'2015-01-01');
insert into status values (2,1,3,'2015-01-01');
insert into status values (3,1,2,'2015-01-01');
insert into status values (4,2,1,'2015-01-01');

insert into project values (1,'My project', 1);
insert into project values (2,'No more', 0);
insert into project values (3,'Other project', 1);


select
    p.title,
    max(s.change_date)
from
    project p
    left outer join status s on s.proj = p.id
where
    p.active = 1
group by 
    p.title
;
```

The output looks like this:

```
+ ------------- + ----------------------- +
| title         | max(s.change_date)      |
+ ------------- + ----------------------- +
| My project    | 2015-01-01              |
| Other project |                         |
+ ------------- + ----------------------- +
2 rows
```